# No Response From Developer - Do I Need To Create A New Account

Tags: twilio

**Note: I am not sure if this right to post on StackOverflow, however this is the link that the Twilio website provides for community support.**

I paid a developer a deposit to work on an app that i am building, however he has not replied to me in 2 weeks, so i am going to move on without him (i'll follow it up offline).

I gave him access to my twilio account. Could i run into problems now? I have now changed the passwords to my twilio account, however i am sure he can still use the api keys etc.

Should i just create a new twilio account, or can you please advise as to what i should do, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is off topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: so twilio should say so... not everything to do with support is a programming matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [change your API auth token](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/what-is-the-auth-token-and-how-can-i-change-it) to remove API access from the prior developer.